# Connecting Outlook to a lightweight EAS server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, activesync

I can connect my iPhone to my company's email server and check email... I can also connect the built in windows 10 mail client to this same server and check my email.  But I cannot connect to the server in Outlook 2016 on Windows 10, as my organization does not (and will not) have Outlook Anywhere enabled.  If I try to configure Outlook to use the Exchange ActiveSync server I get an error that the server cannot be found (it can using iPhone and Win10 client).

This seems kind of silly to me.  Is there any way via configuration to get this to work with outlook?  Or some proxy/hack or anything?

Comment: Outlook Anywhere is the name for configuring an Exchange server to make ActiveSync accessible remotely (over HTTPS). So if the former is not enabled, the latter is not an available connection protocol. Outlook should support the other protocols being used by your other mail clients...IMAP or POP3 perhaps?

Comment: Nope, somehow this isn't the case.  I think mail clients for mobile devices (the win10 mail client can be used in tablet mode) work, while the native Outlook does not.  Tried every type of server available with no luck.  The options aren't the same either.

Comment: If the Windows Mail app is connecting via EAS, then Outlook can too. Perhaps your organization hasn't properly configured the AutoDiscover DNS settings required for Outlook to automatically find the Exchange server. Do you know the external address of the Exchange server so that you can manually enter it into Outlook?

Comment: I do know the external address of the exchange server.  If I try to connect using outlook I get the error described above.  Connecting to that server using iPhone or the win10 client works fine.

Comment: Try using the [Exchange Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com).